# Flutter app login Exception has occurred. PlatformException error

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I have a flutter app but every time I login I get an exception error and I have to press f5 to ensure the process is completed. This is the error

```
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(error, Task io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.MethodCallHandlerImpl$1@f33e5c6 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@63f5987[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], null, java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.MethodCallHandlerImpl$1@f33e5c6 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@63f5987[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2085)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1394)
    at io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.MethodCallHandlerImpl.commitAsync(MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:137)
    at io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.MethodCallHandlerImpl.onMethodCall(MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:96)
    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922)
))
```

Comment: Share the code triggering this error.

Comment: I downgraded the shared preferences package and restarted the IDE. It seems to have solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should downgrade to

> shared_preferences: 2.0.1

not

> shared_preferences: ^2.0.1

if you used the beta version or use the stable version

> shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4

Answer (score 1):

It seems the bug is fixed in shared_preferences 2.0.4 (at least for me it worked)

Comment: I'll make a copy of the project and try it out again

Comment: I try with shared_preferences 2.0.4 but still facing same issue....it working perfectly in 2.0.5